# How can I get relative path of the folders in my android project?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, resources

How can I get the relative path of the folders in my project using code?

I've created a new folder in my project and I want its relative path so no matter where the app is, the path will be correct.

I'm trying to do it in my class which extends [`android.app.Activity`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html).

Perhaps something similar to ["get file path from asset"](http://www.mail-archive.com/android-developers@googlegroups.com/msg90782.html).

Answer (score 25):

Make use of the classpath.

```
ClassLoader classLoader = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();
URL url = classLoader.getResource("path/to/folder");
File file = new File(url.toURI());
// ...
```

Comment: If by "path/to/folder" you mean that I need to insert the path to the project folder so what is the point in it....?

Comment: It's relative to the classpath root. You don't need `c:/absolute/path/to/java/program` in front of it. Try the above. Print the outcome of `url` or `file`. Play with it and you'll understand.

Comment: I still don't understand what do I put instead of -> "path/to/folder"

Comment: Well, the path to the desired folder. Start with an empty string `""` and see.

Comment: Isn't your problem more that you don't understand what the classpath is?

Comment: @Alex Kapustian To make a relative pathname, you use stuff like "..\myFolder\myFile" to reference the myFile in myFolder, which is in the same directory as the folder your program is in. ".." is like the 'up one' button in your filesystem browser.

Answer (score 20):

Are you looking for the root folder of the application? Then I would use

```
 String path = getClass().getClassLoader().getResource(".").getPath();
```

to actually "find out where I am".

Comment: I tried this before and I get "/" but this isn't right. (cause when I try to find a file it doesn't exists)

Comment: On which platform/OS are you running? Just "/" would indicate Unix/linux/OSX, and that you're running your application from the root path of the file system. If that's not correct, please give more info.

Comment: My OS is win7 the path is: "D:\Eclipse\Workspace\Project Name"
Don't forget that this is an android app that I'm running using emulator

Comment: This little snippet of code helped me debug a strange problem I was having with obtaining classpath resources in someone else's integration test suite. Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

```
File relativeFile = new File(getClass().getResource("/icons/forIcon.png").toURI());
myJFrame.setIconImage(tk.getImage(relativeFile.getAbsolutePath()));
```

Answer (score 2):

With this I found my project path:

```
new File("").getAbsolutePath();
```

this return "c:\Projects\SampleProject"

Answer (score 0):

You can check this sample code to understand how you can access the relative path using the java sample code

```
import java.io.File;

public class MainClass {

  public static void main(String[] args) {

    File relative = new File("html/javafaq/index.html");

    System.out.println("relative: ");
    System.out.println(relative.getName());
    System.out.println(relative.getPath());
  }
}
```

Here getPath will display the relative path of the file.

Comment: This is the wrong way. The path will be relative to the working directory. I.e. the folder from which you **executed** the program, not the folder where the program itself is running in. Never use relative paths in `java.io.File`, that's only portability trouble.

Comment: @BalusC, Can you suggest any other way?

Answer (score 0):

In Android, application-level meta data is accessed through the [`Context`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html) reference, which an activity is a descendant of.

For example, you can get the source directory via the `getApplicationInfo().sourceDir` property.
There are methods for other folders as well (assets directory, data dir, database dir, etc.).

Comment: I didn't find how can I get the app path with this.can you be more specific?

Comment: This way I can get only folders that are in the package.
I need to get a relative path to a folder that I created inside the project (not inside the package). Folder like assets.
Can you give me the function that can do it?

Answer (score -1):

Generally we want to add images, txt, doc and etc files inside our Java project and specific folder such as /images.
I found in search that in JAVA, we can get path from Root to folder which we specify as,

```
String myStorageFolder= "/images"; // this is folder name in where I want to store files.

String getImageFolderPath= request.getServletContext().getRealPath(myStorageFolder);
```

Here, request is object of HttpServletRequest. It will get the whole path from Root to /images folder. You will get output like,

> C:\Users\STARK\Workspaces\MyEclipse.metadata.me_tcat7\webapps\JavaProject\images

Answer (score -2):

With `System.getProperty("user.dir")` you get the **"Base of non-absolute paths"** look at

[Java Library Description](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/System.html#getProperty%28java.lang.String%29)