# Setting a file location without hard coding in java

Tags: java, file

Is there a way I could use some functions for setting the location(directory) of my files on the fly?

Every time I use to hardcode file location like this

```
    String folder = "/Users/...../Desktop/sample";
    File dir = new File(folder);
    File[] files = dir.listFiles();
```

is there any method where I can avoid hardcoding? The location I'm using isn't my current directory.

Suggestions or help in this regard appreciated. :)

Comment: You could use property files or parameters... is that all?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2698002/how-can-i-get-relative-path-of-the-folders-in-my-project-java

Comment: @vainolo again in property files I'll hardcode the directory right? my question is , is there a method which can replace hardcoding?

Comment: @Zohaib..  That link has not got what OP wants..\

Comment: are u asking "finding the location" or "setting the location" ?

Comment: @VincenzoSanchez Sorry ya setting, I'll edit my question

Comment: @NiranjanSubramanian.. Why don't you want to hardcode the path anywhere?? That would mean, your code will search for the appropriate path to get there.. Even if you get a method to do that.. Won't that me so much inefficient?? As it will require so much of directory access??

Comment: Did you mean something like System.getProperty("user.dir"). No offensive, the question is little vague

Comment: @RohitJain Ya right I agree, but I'm just curious to know if there is a way to avoid hardcoding and why I'm so specific is I'm using multiple directories in my code so I find it quite clumsy to hardcode, anyway I'll use property files

Comment: @MadProgrammer No I didn't mean that. My question is simple is there a way in java where I can find the path I need and set it without hardcoding it explicitly.

Comment: @NiranjanSubramanian What do you mean by "find"? Do you really mean search the hard drive? If so: What if there are duplicates?

Comment: @Baz Well find in sense I meant locate the directory,

Comment: @NiranjanSubramanian Now you are just using a synonym for "find". Please elaborate...

Comment: @Baz Suppose this is my directory location Users/.../input 
is there any function or a way in java which if used would be equivalent to users/..input i.e my directory. But I do know other alternatives like using property files or using relative path.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As I see it some rather simple ways are feasible, but might not exactly be what you want:

**Navigate from the classpath**

```
ClassLoader cl = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();
URL url = cl.getResource("relative/path/from/classpath");
```

or

```
String path = getClass().getClassLoader().getResource(".").getPath();
```

---

**Use a property file containing an entry for the path**

```
Properties properties = new Properties();
properties.load(new FileInputStream("filename.properties"));
properties.getProperty("PATH")
```

where in your property file you would have a line like

```
PATH = the/absolute/path
```

---

**Use environment variables**

```
System.getenv("THE_PATH_ENV")
```

Where you would store the path in the environment variables (if applicable for your OS).

---

**Give the path as a parameter**
Well, that one is pretty straightforward... Just access the string array in main...

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    String path = args[0]; //Or at whatever position it is in your parameter list
    ..
```

---

Alternatively I could think that it is possible to use the Java file system commands to manually traverse a directory structure and search for something in it. I would however not advise to do this, as this is not what they're made for. If at all I guess I'd fall back on some 3rd party API.

Answer (score 0):

[How can I get relative path of the folders in my android project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2698002/how-can-i-get-relative-path-of-the-folders-in-my-project-java)

Place a folder in project hierarchy, get relative path to the project, append/hardcode folder name and your file name. You would be only hardcoding file name or last folder name at the end.

Answer (score 0):

First you can create a property file, where your path is stored (you can run this once and use the file later with you programm):

```
/* Create/save properties once */

Properties prop = new Properties();

prop.setProperty("filePath", "/myPath/");

FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("sampleprops.xml");
prop.storeToXML(fos, "File configuration");
fos.close();
```

Second you can load the properties where you want in your code:

```
Properties prop = new Properties();
FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("sampleprops.xml");
prop.loadFromXML(fis);

File dir = new File(prop.getProperty("filePath"));
File[] files = dir.listFiles();
```

You just have to make sure, that you have access to the sampleprops.xml file (should be in the classpath of your application). This way you can configure the path you want to use from an extermal configuration file.