# Error being displayed when no evident errors occuring in java

Tags: java

I have a program that is trying to read information from the file "concerts.txt". I have it in the root file of my folder, and even though I am 100% positive the file exists, it is still returning the "Error: File Not Found" exception. I have tried moving it around from the source folder to the root project folder, as well as putting in the whole address of the file ("C:...") and nothing seems to be working. I continue to get the error message, seemingly no matter what I do. Also, I tried moving the try catch block into the class containing the constructor ConcertEvent, and all that did was grab the first instances of the data written in all three instances of the ConcertEvent. I'm not sure how I would change this to where it grabs the correct data (concert1's name should be Maroon 5, concert2's name should be One Direction however both instance's names as of now appear as Maroon 5) Please help me!

Also, I attached the constructor and .txt file I should be reading from

```
public class ConcertDriver
{
    private static String name = null;
    private static char orderType = ' ';
    private static int numTicketsOrdered = 0;
    private static String bandName = null;
    private static double ticketPrice = 0;
    private static int showCapacity = 0;
    private static double amountOwed = 0;
    private static boolean answer = true;
    private static int response = 0;
    private static Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

    public static void main(String[] args)

    {
        try
        {
            Scanner input = new Scanner(new File("concerts.txt"));
            ConcertEvent concert1 = new ConcertEvent(input);
            ConcertEvent concert2 = new ConcertEvent(input);
            ConcertEvent concert3 = new ConcertEvent(input);


            System.out.println("Redbird Concert Hall");
            System.out.println();
            System.out.println("Please choose your concert:");
            System.out.println("1. " + concert1.getBandName());
            System.out.println("2. " + concert2.getBandName());
            System.out.println("3. " + concert3.getBandName());
            System.out.println("4. Quit");
            System.out.println();
            response = keyboard.nextInt();
            while(answer)
            {
                switch(response)
                {
                    case 1:
                    {
                        manageSales(concert1);
                    }
                    case 2:
                    {
                        manageSales(concert2);
                    }
                    case 3:
                    {
                        manageSales(concert3);
                    }
                    case 4:
                    {
                        answer = false;
                        FileWriter output = new FileWriter(new File("report.txt"));
                        output.write(concert1.getBandName() + "\n");
                        output.write(concert1.getShowCapacity() + "\n");
                        output.write(concert1.getTotalTicketsSold() + "\n");
                        output.write(concert2.getBandName() + "\n");
                        output.write(concert2.getShowCapacity() + "\n");
                        output.write(concert2.getTotalTicketsSold() + "\n");
                        output.write(concert3.getBandName() + "\n");
                        output.write(concert3.getShowCapacity() + "\n");
                        output.write(concert3.getTotalTicketsSold() + "\n");
                    }
                    default:
                    {
                        System.out.println("Invalid option, please try again.");
                    }
                }               
            }
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println("Error: File Not Found");
        }
    }
    /*
     * Handles sales, and uses other private helper methods to confirm ticket amounts and calculate necessary data
     */
    private static void manageSales(ConcertEvent concert)
    {
        bandName = concert.getBandName();
        showCapacity = concert.getShowCapacity();
        ticketPrice = concert.getTicketPrice();

        System.out.println("There are " + showCapacity + " tickets remaining for " + bandName + ".");
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("Enter your first and last name:");
        name = keyboard.nextLine();
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("How is your order placed? B for box office or P for phone");
        orderType = keyboard.next().toUpperCase().charAt(0);
        ticketPrice = concert.getTicketPrice();
        if(orderType == 'P')
        {
            ticketPrice += 4; 
        }
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("How many tickets would you like?");
        numTicketsOrdered = keyboard.nextInt();
        confirmAmount(numTicketsOrdered, concert);

    }
    /*
     * Checks to make sure that there is enough tickets available for sale
     */
    private static void confirmAmount(int numTickets, ConcertEvent concert)
    {
        if(numTickets > showCapacity)
        {
            System.out.println("You asked for " + numTicketsOrdered + " to "
                    + concert.getBandName() + ", but there are only "
                    + concert.getShowCapacity() + " tickets remaining.");
        }
        else    
        {
            amountOwed = ConcertCalculator.calculate(numTicketsOrdered, concert.getTicketPrice());
            printReceipt(bandName, name, numTicketsOrdered, amountOwed);
        }
    }
    /*
     * Prints receipt for purchase
     */
    private static void printReceipt(String bandName, String name, int numTickets, double amountOwed)
    {
        System.out.println("Concert: " + bandName);
        System.out.println("Name: " + name);
        System.out.println("Number tickets: " + numTickets);
        System.out.println("Amount owed: " + amountOwed);
    }
}




public ConcertEvent(Scanner input)
    {
        try
        {
        input = new Scanner(new File("concerts.txt"));
                bandName = input.nextLine();
                showCapacity = input.nextInt();
                ticketPrice = input.nextDouble();
                input.nextLine();
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println("Error: file not found");
        }

Maroon 5
15
40
One Direction
10
50
Pearl Jam
20
30
```

Comment: Assign the `new File(..)` to a `File` variable and log its path.

Comment: Try changing the path to `"./concerts.txt"` and try printing a `System.out.println(new File("./").getAbsolutePath())` to see where it ends up. There are better ways to get a path relative to the application but `./` is a cheap (unreliable!) way.

Answer (score 0):

This:

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(new File("concerts.txt"));
```

Will look for the file at the user's directory, not at the root directory. You can find the user's directory by putting `System.out.println(System.getProperty("user.dir"));` somewhere in your code. If you want to get a file at a specific location, you may need to use the full path to the file.

Alternatively, it's often better to get these resources *as resources* via Class's `getResourceAsStream(...)` method. If you use this, the path to the resource (here your text file) will be relative to the path to your class files.

Answer (score 0):

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2698002/how-can-i-get-relative-path-of-the-folders-in-my-project) you can see how you can view the relative path using classpath.

If you know the relative location of your file, then you can easily reach the root of the project and from there your file.