# How do i add a row to an existing csv file in my Android application?

Tags: java, android

I'm writing an activity to add a row to an existing csv file i have in my res/raw folder, reading here and there i found that i should use Filewriter like so:

```
FileWriter pw = new FileWriter("../../res/raw/numbers.csv", true);

pw.append(mate + ";" + loc);
```

however, i tried a few combinations of file names but i always get this error:

```
 java.lang.RuntimeException: Error while closing input stream: java.io.FileNotFoundException: ../../res/raw/numbers.csv (No such file or directory)
```

I'm absolutely sure the file is there but i just can't seem to find it, so i guess i'm using the wrong file name, any help will be greatly appreciated!

Edit: 
i tried this

`FileWriter pw = new FileWriter(getResources().getResourceEntryName(R.raw.numbers), true);`

and got this slightly different exception:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Error while closing input stream: java.io.FileNotFoundException: numbers (Read-only file system)
```

Comment: Can you try it with the absolute path instead of a relative one? Maybe this question is relevant for you: https://stackoverflow.com/q/2698002/8014273.

Comment: I couldn't get any of them to work, i got `java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String java.net.URL.getPath()' on a null object reference` on the only one i was able to get running.

Comment: Files in res/raw are readonly.

Comment: so can i just move the file? i also read from it in a different activity.